# Integral in $\mathbb R^n$: $\int_{|y|< |x|/2} \frac{1}{(1+|y|)^n}dy \leq C(1+ \ln |x|)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Consider an integral in $\mathbb R^n$: $\int_{|y|< |x|/2} \frac{1}{(1+|y|)^n}dy$, why is it $\leq C(1+ \ln |x|)$ for some constant $C$? By polar coordinates: the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{|x|/2} \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^n}dy$. Then how to proceed to get the bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In converting to polar coordinates you forgot a factor corresponding to the volume of the sphere, but that's not too important. Split the integral into two parts:
$$\int_0^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^n}\,dr} = \int_0^{1}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^n}\,dr} + \int_1^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^n}\,dr}.$$
The first part is just some constant, say $C'$. (In fact, notice $C'\le 1$.) The second part can be estimated by
$$\int_1^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^n}\,dr} \le \int_1^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^n}\,dr} = \ln\left(\frac{|x|}{2}\right)\le\ln(|x|). $$
Taking $C=1$ (times the aforementioned volume constant) gives the desired result.

(I'm also assuming here that $|x|$ is large; the result would of course hold for all $x$ by adjusting the constant appropriately.)

Comment: How to apply to this one? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440021/bound-of-integral-in-mathbb-rn-int-y-x-2-frac11ypdy)