# Bound of integral in $\mathbb R^n$: $\int_{|y|< |x|/2} \frac{1}{(1+|y|)^p}dy $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Similar to this post ([Integral in $\mathbb R^n$: $\int_{|y|< |x|/2} \frac{1}{(1+|y|)^n}dy \leq C(1+ \ln |x|)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438273/integral-in-mathbb-rn-int-y-x-2-frac11yndy-leq-c1-l)), but what if we change the power in the denominator, i.e. Consider an integral in $\mathbb R^n$: $\int_{|y|< |x|/2} \frac{1}{(1+|y|)^p}dy$, where $n < p < n+1$. By polar coordinates: the integral becomes $\omega_n \int_{0}^{|x|/2} \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^p}dr$. Then how to proceed to get the bound? I think it's just a bound of constant $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially like the linked post:
$$
\int_0^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^p}\,dr} =
\int_0^1{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^p}\,dr} +
\int_1^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^p}\,dr}.
$$
$$\int_0^1{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^p}\,dr} = \text{constant},$$
$$
\int_1^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^p}\,dr}\le
\int_1^{|x|/2}{\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^p}\,dr} =
\frac{(|x|/2)^{n-p}}{n - p} + \frac{1}{p - n}.
$$
And if $n < p$ ...